# Whats the correct way to reboot a Mac which is managed by Apple Remote Desktop?

Tags: mac-mini, ssh, remote-desktop, remote-control, apple-remote-desktop

I have a headless 2012 Mac Mini running macOS Catalina which is managed with Apple Remote Desktop and `ssh` by my other MacBooks (running macOS Mojave).

The problem is that when I need to reboot the remote Mac Mini, after it boots I cannot log into it with Apple Remote Desktop or with `ssh` until I physically go over to the machine, attach a monitor, keyboard, and mouse, and log into the main local admin account. Once I do this, I can then use Apple Remote Desktop and ssh, and the Mac Mini has Mac Server running as well to (supposedly) help keep it accessible on the network.

I want to be able to reboot the remote Mac Mini in such a way that it will start with `ssh` and Apple Remote Desktop available, so that I could at least login to its main local admin account via ARD for the admin user's services to start.

Is there a way to do this? I could not find anything relevant on Google.

Comment: What does `sudo fdesetup authrestart` say in terminal when it’s running?

Comment: Does setting it to auto-login work, or is it a specific headless trait? I have one Mac I almost exclusively handle over Remote Desktop, but it does have peripherals attached.